# How to add additional (multiple) values to session without overwriting the existing array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

When I try to add additional data to an session array it overwrites the old ones. Is there a way to add multiple values to session array without overwriting the old one or have I to use push one by one?

Here for example:

```php
session()->put([
  'parent'=>[
     'name'=>'jhon', 
     'surname'=>'doe', 
  ] 
]);
```

Now with `session()->all()` I get:

```php
[
   "parent" => [
      "name" => "jhon",
      "surname" => "doe",
   ],
]
```

When I want to add additional values with put for example:

```php
session()->put([
  'parent'=>[
     'gender'=>'male', 
     'phone'=>'000000', 
  ] 
]);
```

No I get this with `session()->all()`:

```php
[
   "parent" => [
     "gender" => "male", 
     "phone" => "000000",
   ],
]
```

But I want:

```php
[
   "parent" => [
      "name" => "jhon",
      "surname" => "doe",
      "gender" => "male", 
      "phone" => "000000",
   ],
]
```

So how can I add additional (multiple) data to an existing session array without touching the old ones?

Comment: Did you tried this ?

session->put([
 "parent" => [
  "gender" => "male", 
  "phone" => "000000",
 ]+[
      "phone" => "000000",
 ]
]);

Comment: Yes @GautamPatadiya but this works but is not convenient for me.

Comment: May be you have to try merge before add in session that helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @AlexeyMezenin and @GautamPatadiya answers I found this way which looks very convenient to me. Please correct if this seems wrong to you or there is a better way you konw.

```
session()->put([
  'parent'=>[
     'name'=>'jhon', 
     'surname'=>'doe', 
  ] 
]);
```

Then just add itself to the new array like:

```
session()->put([
  'parent'=>[
     'gender'=>'male', 
     'phone'=>'000000', 
  ] + session('parent');
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read data first, modify it and save it again. Just an example:

```
$data = session('parent');

$data['gender'] = 'male';
$data['phone'] = '000000';

session(['parent' => $data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session()->push()` method as given [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#storing-data)
For e.g. 
1) Put the data first time using `session()->put()`

```
session()->put([
  'parent'=>[
     'name'=>'jhon', 
     'surname'=>'doe', 
  ] 
]);
```

2) Now Push the data you want to add using `session()->push()`

```
session()->push('parent',[
   'gender'=>'male', 
   'phone'=>'000000', 
]);
```

Comment: i tried this but the second array you add with push is placed under 0. like [
     "parent" => [
       "name" => "jhon",
       "surname" => "doe",
       0 => [
         "gender" => "male",
         "phone" => "000000",
       ],
     ],
   ]

Comment: the session()->push() method has $array[] = $value; which creates a index 0 thus it creates the pushed variables under [0].